# .Ge Domain does not have TXT record?

Tags: dns, firebase-hosting

I bought a .ge domain and the control panel only has options to update NameSpace and IP (see screenshot below).  I contacted support and they said I can't edit TXT records?

I want to verify ownership of the domain so I can forward it to my Firebase hosting url.  Is this possible given I can only update NameSpace and IP?

[image: control panel of domain company]